# How to get the stack-trace in several implementations in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

I'm trying to make a library that I'm writing portable between the different Common Lisp implementations, I need a function like SBCL called `sb-debug:list-backtrace` which returns a list with stake-trace, but I did not find any of them, I'm looking for your documentation, and I'll continue, and I'll update with what I can get here, but I ask for help from anyone who has already used it and you know which function of the implementations below can return me a stack-trace list.

```
(defun get-stack-trace ()
  #+sbcl (sb-debug:list-backtrace)
  #+clisp (?)
  #+cmu (?)
  #+mcl (?)
  #+excl (?)
  #+abcl (?)
  #+cll (?)
  #+clasp (?)
  #+ecl (?)
  #+mezzano (?)
  #+mkcl (?))
```

True that I do not need all this portability, but since it's just this function, I do not see why not try to port for as many implementations as you can get.

Comment: https://github.com/gwkkwg/trivial-backtrace

Comment: also https://github.com/Shinmera/dissect "when a lot of projects use the “trivial-backtrace” system that just gives them a string with a backtrace, Dissect allows you to capture, step, and completely inspect the stack trace on a variety of Lisp implementations". Seen on https://github.com/CodyReichert/awesome-cl